# The dangers of SaveDefinitions --- should this really happen?

Tags: manipulate, cdf-format, variable-definitions

I have been bitten hard by [`SaveDefinitions -> True`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SaveDefinitions.html).  I'll describe in detail what happened below.

My questions are: Is this a bug?  What is the most convenient workaround?

---

Consider a definition issued like this:

```
Block[{x, y}, f[x_, y_] = x + y;]
```

Why didn't I use `:=` instead?  Because the expression that stands in place of `x+y` in my actual problem is computed (symbolically) within the `Block` so (numerical) evaluations of `f` are going to be sufficiently fast.

We can check the definition:

```
?f
```

> f[x_,y_]=x+y

Now let's give `x` a value ...

```
x = 1
```

... and test that `f` still works as expected:

```
f[0, 0]
```

> 0 (* as expected *)

Let's use `f` in `Manipulate` with `SaveDefinitions -> True` ...

```
Manipulate[f[a, b], {a, -1, 1}, {b, -1, 1}, SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

... and check that it works again:

```
f[0, 0]
```

> 1 (* oops!! *)

```
?f

f[x_, y_] = 1 + y
```

The definition of `f` has been rewritten *and changed to something else* as a side effect of `SaveDefinitions`.

What is the morale?  Probably that `SaveDefinitions` and `Set` are not safe to use together.

Note that what happened here is different form the situation when the definition of `f` is overwritten just because a notebook containing a manipulate with SaveDefinitions has been opened.

---

My current workaround is to use the following hack to "neutralize" the `HoldAll` attribute of `SetDelayed`:

```
Block[{x, y},
 (f[x_, y_] := #) &[x + y];]
```

Alternative suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I have the feeling it won't get much better than using `Evaluate` or your alternative

Comment: There's always the possibility to post process the `Manipulate`

Comment: @Rojo yes, maybe it's not the best *question* ... do you think I should delete?

Comment: Definately not. I hadn't realised about this, this can be useful. I'll post what I suggested as an answer

Comment: Didn't I tell you before that [SaveDefinitions is dangerous](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579644/savedefinitions-considered-dangerous)?

Comment: Although this is posed as problem with `Manipulate`, hasn't this behavior been a problem with `Save` for a much longer time? I suspect that the dependency tracing mechanism used in `Save` is just showing up again.

Comment: @Szabolcs, you could use `With` to inject the expr or make a function that returns a function. That will be much cleaner and much more modular.

Comment: I never use `SaveDefinitions`.  Just never.  It's terribly convenient, but for my purposes, it is just not sufficiently predictable.  And it can sometimes be incredibly inefficient (e.g., when it stores ridiculous amounts of definitions which were hidden behind a `Needs` or `Get`).

Comment: @JohnFultz Isn't it necessary before exporting a Manipulate to a CDF?  (I don't have much experience with CDFs but I needed to create some self-contained examples for someone's presentation.)

Comment: @Szabolcs All `SaveDefinitions` does is to auto-construct an `Initialization` option for you.  I'm a control freak.  Let me construct my own `Initialization` option.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using `InputForm` on your `Manipulate` reveals (like it did in my [SaveDefinitions Considered Dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579644/savedefinitions-considered-dangerous) post) that it contains the following:

```
Manipulate[f[a, b], {a, -1, 1}, {b, -1, 1}, Initialization :> {f[x_, y_] = x + y, x = 1}]
```

So, it actually stores two definitions, one for `f` and one for x. This actually makes sense, as `SaveDefinitions`'s  task is to store any definitions that the `Manipulate` depends on. When it is checking for this, it finds `f`, stores its definition and probably then checks whether `f`itself has any dependencies that need to be taken into account.It checks `x` and finds a definition in the `` Global` `` namespace, so this is stored as well.

Comment: @kuba ... or just use `\[FormalX]` and `\[FormalY]` symbols in your definitions. Can't go wrong with that.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware of this. Thanks :)

Comment: More people should use the `InputForm` technique.  Bravo to you.

Comment: @JohnFultz Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

This seems to be a very easy way to bite yourself in the foot (non-flexible programmers this is not for you). I also have the habit of doing those blocked set-based definitions. It's probably time to change the habit now.

It seems to me that `SaveDefinition` extracts the definitions of the symbols required by the `Manipulate`, as you entered them. If you used `:=`, then it will be stored as `:=`, if `=` then `=`. So, if you made a definition with `=` that required certain localization, that localization won't be captured by `SaveDefinitions`.

I am not sure how to avoid that, other than using `:=` in the first place and ensuring what you pass to `:=` is already the final form of the rhs you desire.

So, your own suggestion looks good. The natural alternative is using `f[x_, y_]:=Evaluate[...]`.

Another attempt of an alternative could be to modify your `Manipulate` after creation, changing the `Set`-based definitions to `SetDelayed` (assuming this doesn't bring other unintended sideeffects).

An implementation could be (please @Mr.Wizard, prettify this if you see a nice way. I haven't got the time or brains these days)

```
postProcessTheManipulate[m_Manipulate] :=
 Replace[m // ToBoxes // ToExpression, (Initialization :> l_List) :> 
   Block[{},
    (Replace[Hold@l, 
        HoldPattern@
          Set[args : PatternSequence[Except[_Symbol], ___]] :> 
         SetDelayed[args], {2}] /. 
       Hold[ll_] :> (Initialization :> ll)) /; True], {1}]
```

To be used

```
Manipulate[f[a, b], {a, -1, 1}, {b, -1, 1}, 
  SaveDefinitions -> True] // postProcessTheManipulate
```

---

*Edit by Mr.Wizard* -- As requested here is a terse version, assuming it is safe to replace all `Set` expressions at level one on the RHS of `Initialization`:

```
pptm[m_Manipulate] :=
 Replace[m // ToBoxes // ToExpression,
   init : (Initialization :> _) :>
     RuleCondition @ Replace[init, Verbatim[Set][x__] :> SetDelayed[x], {2}],
   {1}
 ]
```

Comment: *Bite* yourself in the foot?  Around here we say *shoot* yourself in the foot, which somehow makes a lot more sense. :^)

Comment: Could you explain the reason for `args : PatternSequence[Except[_Symbol], ___]` -- at the moment I don't see the need for the complex pattern.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I was lazy to think whether there was a statistically significant disadvantage to changing ALL `=` to `:=` so I just tried to prevent the changing in the obvious `Set`'s kingdom: the `x=something;`-land

Comment: By providing the `Manipulate` with `Method -> {"ExtraVariables" :> {f}}`  `f` will get localized and the original un-delayed definition wont be contaminated. ( `{f,x}` in Mr.Wizards version )

Comment: I *think* it should be safe, so for the sake of shorter code I left it out.  Now people have options.

Comment: Thanks @Mr.Wizard! Way clearer code now

Comment: @ssch Wow! That's nice. Where did you get that information from? Looking at the source code?

Comment: @Rolf I used the Spelunking package on `Manipulate` to see how it created the definitions, ran into it in Manipulate\`Dump\`MakeManipulateBoxes. Would be even nicer if SaveDefinitions localized things automatically to avoid the problem Sjoerd linked

Comment: @ssch Cool. Yes, SaveDefinitions, Initialization are not developer-friendly functions (or, not enough documented). Maybe the FrontEnd team thinks that $CellContext` is enough localization (I wished one could turn that off btw.).

Comment: @ssch That prevents the interaction with `f` but the `Manipulate` still leaks the setting for x. After a restart the notebook with that `Manipulate` panel will have `x` defined as 1. So you have to add all variables (i.e., x and y) to the list.