# Initial values in Manipulate are hijacked by existing global variable values

Tags: manipulate

Is the following behaviour a bug?  It's the same in all versions between 9.0-10.2.0.

Let's try this simple `Manipulate` with the initial value of `a` set to `1`:

```
Manipulate[Style[a, Large], {{a, 1}, 0, 2}, SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now let us do the same, but set a value to the global `a` first:

```
a = 0.5;

Manipulate[Style[a, Large], {{a, 1}, 0, 2}, SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The initial value of the local `a` (set to `1` in the `Manipulate`) is hijacked by the global value of `a`.  It now shows as `0.5` instead of `1`.

This only happens with `SaveDefinitions -> True`.

Is this a bug or is it expected behaviour?

---

**Analysis:**  As Michael points out in the comments, the `SaveDefintions` option causes `a=0.5` to be recorded in the `Initialization` option.  The `Manipulate` evaluates to this InputForm:

```
Manipulate[Style[a, Large], {{a, 0.5}, 0, 2}, Initialization :> {a = 0.5}]
```

Normally `SaveDefinitions -> True` is supposed to record every symbol that's used in the `Manipulate`, but apparently it neglects to filter out those that are used as parameters.

So is it reasonable to record the global value of `a`?  In some cases it might be.  Consider

```
a = 1;
f[] := a

Manipulate[f[] + a, {a, 0, 1}]
```

Is this `Manipulate` going to show `a + 1` as `a` goes from 0..1, or is it going to show `a + a`?

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It shows `a + 1`, as one would expect based on the fact that the parameter is local to the `Manipulate` and shouldn't conflict with global variables.  But the function `f` depends on the global `a`, so if we want to preserve `f`, we also need to preserve the global `a`.  Thus on first sight it seems reasonable that `SaveDefinitions` should save the global `a` (but not that that should influence the local value).

Now let us see what *actually* happens if we try it:

```
Manipulate[f[] + a, {a, 0, 1}, SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Well, it seems `SaveDefinitions` changed the behaviour completely.  Now it shows `a+a` instead of `a+1` ...  I would definitely call this a bug!

Comment: Seems like a bug, in which the symbol `a` in the code triggers a search for a symbol ``Global`a`` with a value (perhaps) that is packaged into the `Initialization` option.  Absolutely no reason I see that such behavior is appropriate here.

Comment: Same behavior in V8.0.4.

Comment: @MichaelE2 It seems we found another, related problem: Will `a=1; f[] := a; Manipulate[f[] + a, {a,0,1}]` show the value of `a + a` or `1 + a`?  It depends on whether we use `SaveDefinitions -> True`!

Comment: Yikes, it redefines `f` (with `SaveDefinitions -> True`)!  Try pasting several outputs into your notebook.  The function `f` is redefined each time to represent the local `a` in the last pasted Manipulate -- for all the other Manipulates!

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes, but that behaviour is actually normal, despite of all the troubles it can bring.  It makes it easy to create self-contained CDFs.  But be very careful with these, or any notebook that has a Manipulate with SaveDefintions!  Once you open the notebook, a bunch of Global symbols will get redefined.  This was the source of hard to reproduce weird unexpected behaviours in many M.SE threads.

Comment: One aspect is normal, but the problem with `a` adds to the trouble (one could always replicate it by copying the `Initialization`). This bug might explain a habit I developed in V6.  I used `SaveDefinitions` a lot. I wrote all functions to be self-contained (with no parameters not explicitly an argument), which is a good habit anyway.  I also deleted all `Manipulate` output under development before quitting for the day.

Comment: We've seen this all before ([32004](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32004/57) and my related piece on StackOverflow). Isn't this a duplicate or a corollary?