# How should I deal with messages being produced by my Manipulate?

Tags: differential-equations, manipulate

I have made a knockoff of John Polking's *dfield* for a web-embedded CDF (via Enterprise *Mathematica*). My code extends that from Belisarius who last year showed me how to use `ClickPane` to store and clear solution curves.

Although clicking on any point of the slope field produces an apparently correct solution curve, an error message `NDSolve::ndsz` is generated by `NDSolve`. Moreover, by choosing an initial value near the point with coordinates (2,-2) and following by moving the "b" slide from its default position, the slope field turns the color pink and I get the message "`InterpolatingFunction::dmval`: Input value {-1.99992} lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used."

```
sf := 
  VectorPlot[{1, diffEq /. {a -> A, b -> B}}, {t, -2, 2}, {x, -2, 2},
    VectorPoints -> 17,
    VectorScale -> {0.03, Automatic, None}, 
    VectorStyle -> {{Red, Arrowheads[0]}}, ImagePadding -> 1, 
    PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"];

f[t_, a_, b_, t0_, x0_] := 
  u[t] /. First[Quiet[NDSolve[{u'[t] == ODE, u[t0] == x0}, u, {t, -2, 2}, 
                  Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"]]];

Manipulate[
  ODE = diffEq /. {a -> A, b -> B} /. x -> u[t];
  ClickPane[
    Show[
      Plot[g, {t, -2, 2}, 
        PlotRange -> 2, Frame -> True, 
        ImageSize -> 400, AspectRatio -> 0.75], 
      sf, 
      Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Point[sp]}]],
    (AppendTo[g, f[t, A, B, #[[1]], #[[2]]]]; {t0, u0} = #; 
     AppendTo[sp, #]) &],
  Style["Enter f(t,x)"],
  {{diffEq, x^2 - a t + b, "dx/dt = "}},
  {{A, 1, "a"}, -4, 4, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled", ControlPlacement -> Bottom},
  {{B, 0, "b"}, -4, 4, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled", ControlPlacement -> Bottom},
  Button["clear", {g = {}; sp = {}}, ImageSize -> {40, 20}], 
  Initialization :> {(
    g = {}; sp = {}; {t0, x0} = {})},
  SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

FYI, the ODE that I have set as an input is the default used in *dfield*.

[image]

The two error messages that I get are probably related.

> NDSolve::ndsz: At t == -1.71226, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected. >>
>
> InterpolatingFunction::dmval: Input value {-1.99992} lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used. >>

I do not have sufficient *Mathematica* chops to fix my problem.

Comment: (1) The `NDSolve::ndsz` message is technically a warning, not an error. It may just be telling you that there is a singularity, which is not an error. (2) You mention error in the singular at first and two errors at the end.  Are they the same error? (3) What do the sliders `a` and `b` do? (4) Look up `Quiet`. There are other ways to handle the message, but I'm not sure I understand the question well enough yet. (5) I added the message identifier based on the text in your title.  It helps others who get the same message. If you're getting two different messages, consider adding that one, too.

Comment: @Michael E2: See updated title and clarification of messages

Comment: @m_goldberg We're editing simultaneously -- I thought SE prevented/warned us.  We seem to be clashing here.  Looks ok, now, I think...Look good to you?

Comment: I changed your title and inserted examples of the messages into the body of your question. Your title was inaccurate. Only one of messages is produced by `NDSolve`. The other is produced by `InterpolatingFunction` when `f` is being plotted.

Comment: @MichaelE2. Editing wars are not prevented by SE, unfortunately. The warnings often show up too late. Sorry about the clash. I'm done editing for now.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the `NDSolve::ndsz` error, only the extrapolation error.  Can you specify a setting for `a` and `b`? Or did you use a different `f[x, t]`?  (If you allow arbitrary input for `f`, you are going to get "bad" ODEs.  How do you want to handle such cases that produce messages?)

Comment: @m_goldberg: your revision of my title seems too generic. Why not be more specific as in Michael E2's last comment?

Comment: @Michael E2: Choose an initial value near the point with coordinates (2,-2). Then move the "b" slider just slightly from its default position, b=0, and leave the "a" slider at a=0. Then the slope field turns the color pink and I get the message "InterpolatingFunction::dmval: Input value {-1.99992} lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used."
I can always suppress the messages but not the pink color of the plot. I have not changes the input ODE. 
You bring up a good point - how to guard against "bad" ODEs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Re `NDSolve::ndsz`:*
Using [`WhenEvent`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WhenEvent.html), one can stop the integration before the solution reaches an infinite singularity, which is what is happening with the example differential equation.  I removed the `Quiet` so one might test it.  If the differential equation is changed, then it would be possible to get the message to appear.  Use `Quiet` to suppress it, [`Check`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Check.html) to deal with it.

*Re `InterpolatingFunction::dmval`:*
Using the `NDSolve` option

```
"ExtrapolationHandler" -> {Indeterminate &, "WarningMessage" -> False}
```

prevents extrapolation and turns off the warning message.

*Random changes:*
I incorporated needed definitions in the `Initialization` option instead of `SaveDefinitions`; see [The dangers of SaveDefinitions --- should this really happen?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31998/the-dangers-of-savedefinitions-should-this-really-happen) 
I made the functions explicitly depend on the `Manipulate` variables.  This is just a good habit when developing code, especially `Dynamic` code.  Otherwise, one day it works, and the next a minor change breaks the dynamic updating.
I localized `g` and `sp`.  One might want to localize the functions, too.
I probably did a few other idiosyncratic things as I went along.  None of these had anything to do with the two messages the OP asked about.

```
Manipulate[
 ClickPane[
  Show[
   Plot[g, {t, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> 2, Frame -> True, 
    ImageSize -> 400, AspectRatio -> 0.75],
   sf@dx[diffEq, A, B],
   Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Point[sp]}]],
  (AppendTo[g, f[dx[diffEq, A, B], #]];
    AppendTo[sp, #]) &],

 Style["Enter f(t,x)"],
 {{diffEq, x^2 - a t + b, "dx/dt = "}},
 {{A, 1, "a"}, -4, 4, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled", ControlPlacement -> Bottom},
 {{B, 0, "b"}, -4, 4, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled", ControlPlacement -> Bottom},
 {{g, {}}, ControlType -> None}, {{sp, {}}, ControlType -> None},
 Button["clear", g = {}; sp = {}, ImageSize -> {Automatic, 20}],

 Initialization :> (    (* alternative to SaveDefinitions -> True; *)
   Clear[f, sf, dx]; 
   g = {};
   sp = {};
   dx[de_, a0_, b0_] := de /. {a -> a0, b -> b0};
   sf[dx_] := VectorPlot[{1, dx},
     {t, -2, 2}, {x, -2, 2},
     VectorPoints -> 17, VectorScale -> {0.03, Automatic, None}, 
     VectorStyle -> {{Red, Arrowheads[0]}}, ImagePadding -> 1, 
     PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"];
   f[dx_, {t0_, x0_}] := u[t] /. 
      First@ NDSolve[            (* consider `Quiet`, `Check` to handle NDSolve::ndsz *)
       {u'[t] == dx /. {x -> u[t]}, u[t0] == x0,
        WhenEvent[Abs[u[t]] > 3, "StopIntegration"]},
       u, {t, -2, 2},
       Method -> "StiffnessSwitching", 
       "ExtrapolationHandler" -> {Indeterminate &, "WarningMessage" -> False}];
   )]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

A somewhat more robust way might be to use the functionality for this sort of thing built into [`VectorPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VectorPlot.html).  One significant difference is that it will not draw solutions when they get too close to one another, and no solution if it starts too close to another solution.  It allows one to simplify the code considerably since `VectorPlot` handles all the `NDSolve` stuff under the hood.

Another difference is that the curves automatically change when the `a` or `b` sliders are changed, since `VectorPlot` recomputes the stream lines.

```
Manipulate[
 ClickPane[
  Show[
   VectorPlot[{1, dx[diffEq, A, B]}, {t, -2, 2}, {x, -2, 2}, 
    VectorPoints -> 17, VectorScale -> {0.03, Automatic, None}, 
    VectorStyle -> {{Red, Arrowheads[0]}}, ImagePadding -> 1, 
    PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", PlotRange -> 2, Frame -> True, 
    ImageSize -> 400, AspectRatio -> 0.75,
    StreamPoints -> {Thread[
       {sp,
        Table[
         Directive[ColorData[97, i], AbsoluteThickness[1.6]], {i, 
          Length@sp}]}]},
    StreamScale -> None],
   Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Point[sp]}]],
  AppendTo[sp, #] &],

 Style["Enter f(t,x)"],
 {{diffEq, x^2 - a t + b, "dx/dt = "}},
 {{A, 1, "a"}, -4, 4, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled", 
  ControlPlacement -> Bottom},
 {{B, 0, "b"}, -4, 4, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled", 
  ControlPlacement -> Bottom},
 Button["clear", sp = {}, ImageSize -> {Automatic, 20}],

 Initialization :> (
   Clear[dx];
   sp = {};
   dx[de_, a0_, b0_] := de /. {a -> a0, b -> b0};
   )]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

I think your `Quiet` is not in the right place, and you may need another one.

For `f`:

```
f[t_, a_, b_, t0_, x0_] := 
  Quiet[u[t] /. 
    First[NDSolve[{u'[t] == ODE, u[t0] == x0}, u, {t, -2, 2}, 
      Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"]]];
```

gets rid of the NDSolve warning. Then add another `Quiet` around the Plot:

```
Quiet[Plot[g, {t, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> 2, Frame -> True, 
  ImageSize -> 400, AspectRatio -> 0.75]]
```

This removes the `InterpolatingFunction` warning.

Comment: +1. LOL, I didn't even notice the `Quiet` around the `NDSolve`.  I took it that the OP was actually *getting* the singularity warning...

Comment: That did it bill s! All is Quiet now. And I don't get the pink colored plot.

Comment: @Michael E2: I like your formatting touch that enlarges the font for "Enter f(t,x)" and "dx/dt". How do I make the rhs of the ODE, "b-at+x^2" to display in a bigger font size?

Comment: @Stephen I'm not sure to what formatting touch you're referring, but maybe `{{diffEq, x^2 - a t + b, "dx/dt = "}, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14}}` will do what want.

Comment: @Michael E2: Your formatting suggestion is what I wanted.

Comment: @Michael E2: My next iteration will try to control for bad inputs such as 1/x when x=0 or Log[x] when x=<0. I also will make the PlotRange variable: {t, t1, t2}, {x, x1, x2}

Comment: @Michael E2: The Streampoints approach is an elegant solution, especially the fact that parameter changes will change the corresponding curves. I prefer your first approach as it is important to see the entire solution.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Stephen, m_goldberg et al, there is some wonderful possibilities here. I am looking forward to seeing how this progresses.

Answer (score 2):

The following turns off the warning messages, but is not really a good solution, since it doesn't deal with the root problem of the trouble `NDSolve` is having with your differential equation.

```
sf[eq_, A_, B_] := 
  VectorPlot[{1, eq /. {a -> A, b -> B}}, {t, -2, 2}, {x, -2, 2}, 
    VectorPoints -> 17, VectorScale -> {0.03, Automatic, None}, 
    VectorStyle -> {{Red, Arrowheads[0]}}, ImagePadding -> 1,
    PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"]

f[t_, a_, b_, t0_, x0_] := 
   u[t] /. 
     First[Quiet @ NDSolve[{u'[t] == ODE, u[t0] == x0}, u, {t, -2, 2}, 
                     Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"]]

Manipulate[
  ODE = diffEq /. {a -> A, b -> B} /. x -> u[t];
  ClickPane[
    Show[
      Quiet @ Plot[g, {t, -2, 2},
        PlotRange -> 2, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 400, AspectRatio -> 0.75],
      sf[diffEq, A, B],
      Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Point[sp]}]], 
    (AppendTo[g, f[t, A, B, #[[1]], #[[2]]]]; {t0, u0} = #;
     AppendTo[sp, #]) &],
  Style["Enter f(t,x)", 12],
  {{diffEq, x^2 - a t + b, Style["dx/dt = ", 12]}}, 
  {{A, 1, "a"}, -4, 4, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled", ControlPlacement -> Bottom}, 
  {{B, 0, "b"}, -4, 4, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled", ControlPlacement -> Bottom}, 
  Button[Style["Clear", 10], {g = {}; sp = {}}, ImageSize -> {50, 25}],
  Initialization :> (g = {}; sp = {}; {t0, x0} = {}),
  SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

[image: diff_eq]

Answer (score 1):

I've not answered any questions with this example, but I added tmin, tmax, xmin, xmax, and adjusted when to halt the integration. I don't know yet how to handle the Check command in MichaelE2's comment, so that still remains in the code.

```
Manipulate[ClickPane[Show[Plot[g, {t, tmin, tmax},
    PlotRange -> {{tmin, tmax}, {xmin, xmax}},
    Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 400, AspectRatio -> 0.75], 
   sf@dx[diffEq, A, B], 
   Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Point[sp]}]], (AppendTo[g, 
     f[dx[diffEq, A, B], #]];
    AppendTo[sp, #]) &], 
 Style["Enter f(t,x)"], {{diffEq, x^2 - a t + b, "dx/dt = "}},
 Row[{
   Control[{{tmin, -2, "tmin = "}}],
   Spacer[10],
   Control[{{tmax, 10, "tmax = "}}]
   }],
 Row[{
   Control[{{xmin, -4, "xmin = "}}],
   Spacer[10],
   Control[{{xmax, 4, "xmax = "}}]
   }],
 {{A, 1, "a"}, -4, 4, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled", 
  ControlPlacement -> Bottom}, {{B, 0, "b"}, -4, 4, 0.01, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled", ControlPlacement -> Bottom}, {{g, {}}, 
  ControlType -> None}, {{sp, {}}, ControlType -> None}, 
 Button["clear", g = {}; sp = {}, ImageSize -> {Automatic, 20}], 
 Initialization :> ((*alternative to SaveDefinitions\[Rule]True;*)
   Clear[f, sf, dx];
   g = {};
   sp = {};
   dx[de_, a0_, b0_] := de /. {a -> a0, b -> b0};
   sf[dx_] := 
    VectorPlot[{1, dx}, {t, tmin, tmax}, {x, xmin, xmax}, 
     VectorPoints -> 17, VectorScale -> {0.03, Automatic, None}, 
     VectorStyle -> {{Red, Arrowheads[0]}}, ImagePadding -> 1, 
     PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"];
   f[dx_, {t0_, x0_}] := 
    u[t] /. First@
      NDSolve[(*consider `Quiet`,`Check` to handle NDSolve::ndsz*){u'[
           t] == dx /. {x -> u[t]}, u[t0] == x0, 
        WhenEvent[Abs[u[t]] > 2.5 Max[{Abs[xmin], Abs[xmax]}], 
         "StopIntegration"]}, u, {t, tmin, tmax}, 
       Method -> "StiffnessSwitching", 
       "ExtrapolationHandler" -> {Indeterminate &, 
         "WarningMessage" -> False}];)]
```

[image]

I've also adjusted tmin, tmax, xmin, xmax to match the default image in John Polking's dfield program.

[image]

I like the use of keeping the parameters a and b at the bottom, as you can use them in other functions. For example, try (a-x)(b-x).