# SaveDefinitions makes Manipulate take a long time to evaluate

Tags: manipulate

I've noticed that using the `SaveDefinitions` option of Manipulate makes it take a long time to evaluate.

For example, here is a notebook that uses Manipulate to show the frames from a gif (code below):

[image]

Code:

```
Clear["Global`"];
ims = Import["http://imgur.com/download/TbwMsiF"]; (* a 1MB gif *)
Length@ims
ByteCount[ims]

t0 = Now;
AbsoluteTiming[
 Manipulate[ims[[i]],
  {{i, 4, "frame"}, 1, Length@ims, 1, Appearance -> "Open"}]
 ]
t1 = Now;
t1 - t0

FileByteCount[NotebookFileName[]]
```

You can see that `AbsoluteTiming` claims the `Manipulate` call takes less than a millisecond, whereas our two calls to `Now` say it took half a second. Fine.

Adding `SaveDefinitions` makes it take almost 2 minutes, despite `AbsoluteTiming` claiming it ran in a millisecond (code below):

[image]

Code:

```
Clear["Global`"]; 
ims = Import["http://imgur.com/download/TbwMsiF"]; (* a 1MB gif *)
Length@ims
ByteCount[ims]

t0 = Now;
AbsoluteTiming[
 Manipulate[ims[[i]],
  {{i, 4, "frame"}, 1, Length@ims, 1, Appearance -> "Open"},
  SaveDefinitions -> True]
 ]
t1 = Now;
t1 - t0

FileByteCount[NotebookFileName[]]
```

I'm not sure what `Manipulate` is doing for those 2 minutes: you can see from the pic that the whole notebook is only 3 MB.

**Question 1**: Why does it take so long for `SaveDefinitions` to save the 50 frames of the gif into 3 MB?

**Question 2**: Is there a simple workaround for this?

I would really like to use `SaveDefinitions` to make the notebook self-contained, so that I don't have to re-run the notebook every time I open it.

(I'm aware that `SaveDefinitions` is dangerous [[1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31998/the-dangers-of-savedefinitions-should-this-really-happen), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579644/savedefinitions-considered-dangerous)].)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me ignore the first question :)

This should work:

```
ims = Import["http://imgur.com/download/TbwMsiF"];

With[{ims = ims, l = Length@ims},
    Manipulate[
       ims2[[i]]
     , {{i, 4, "frame"}, 1, l, 1, Appearance -> "Open"}
     , {ims2, None}
     , Initialization :> (ims2 = ims)
     , UnsavedVariables :> {ims2}
    ]
]
```

So we inject images to `Initialization` and access it via localized variable `ims2`. `UnsavedVariables` prevents it to save it automatically, we don't need it saved twice.

[What does None mean in a control specification for Manipulate?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17112/5478)

[How can I include functions from a package into a CDF file?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/86674/5478)

Comment: Incredible, many thanks! What is the purpose of the outer `With` statement, and also the `{ims2,None}` argument?

Comment: @ConvexMartian added links.

Comment: Kuba, thanks for the links. I'm still confused about the `With[{ims=ims},...]` idiom. In your second link, you say "We have to use `With` to inject source into `DynamicModule`'s Initialization because `Initialization` is set with `RuleDelayed` which is `HoldRest`." I know what `HoldRest` means, but I don't know why it necessitates the `With[{ims=ims},...]`. I searched around but "mathematica With initialization idiom" doesn't return many useful results...

Comment: @ConvexMartian sorry for a delay please see [7758](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7758/5478)